# Why does my server only write the first line of a file to my client?

Tags: c, file-io, network-programming, server, client

I have two programs, a simple client, and a simple server, and I'm trying to send HTTP GET requests from my client to my server. In this case, I am sending a `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n` request from my client to my server, and I have the server send the contents of `index.html` to my client for it to output to `stdout`. I have managed to do most of this, EXCEPT that the client outputs only the first line of my `index.html` file to `stdout`, and I just cannot see why. What is confusing to me is that, as opposed to this, the `printf()` in my server program is printing the entire `index.html`. Here is a snippet from the server program:

```
#include "csapp.h"

int MAXLEN = 10000;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

       //some initializations and other things

        if(( in = fopen(req, "r")) == NULL){
            rio_writen(connfd, "Couldn't open file\n", MAXLEN);
            exit(0);
        }
        while (fgets(output, 99999, in) != NULL){
            printf("%s", output); //printing entire thing
            write(connfd, output, sizeof(output)); //should write entire file!

        }
        fclose(in);
        Close(connfd);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

And just in case, from my client program, this is how my client reads from my server, although I doubt this is where the problem is happening, as I can read for example, the entire `index.html` from `wwww.google.com` just fine, which makes things even more confusing.

```
int n = Rio_readlineb(&reeo, buffer, MAXLEN);
while(n > 0){
    printf("%s", buffer);
    n = Rio_readlineb(&reeo, buffer, MAXLEN);
}
Close(fd);
exit(0);
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can let me know what is going wrong. Also, csapp.c can be found [here](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/2e/ics2/code/src/csapp.c).

Comment: What is the declaration of `output`?

Comment: `fgets()` only returns a single line from the file. `write(connfd, output, sizeof(output))` will try to write the entire `output` array, not just the amount that was read with `fgets`. You should use `strlen(output)`.

Comment: @Barmar In main, char output[9999];

Comment: So even if the line is only 10 characters long, you're going to write 9999 characters every time.

Comment: Is it `output[9999]` or `output[99999]`? You're reading up to `99999` bytes with `fgets()`, so the buffer needs to be that size.

Comment: You might want to read about `sendfile()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
    while (fgets(output, sizeof(output), in) != NULL){
        printf("%s", output); //printing entire thing
        write(connfd, output, strlen(output));
    }
```

You should use `sizeof` when reading from the file, to ensure that it doesn't try to read more than the buffer size. But when writing, you should only write the part of `buffer` containing the line that was just read. Your code was writing the entire buffer, which includes all the uninitialized bytes.

Comment: I see, I was not fully aware of this. Thank you.